# How to run php properly from the command line

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I'm using the symfony2 framework, 
and I need to run "php app/console" commands frequently, 
however when I run `"php app/console"`
it says

> The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing:
>
> sudo apt-get install php5-cli

this is working though

```
/usr/local/php7/bin/php app/console
```

how can I make `'php'` out of `'/usr/local/php7/bin/php'` for the command line? I'm on linux Mint/Ubuntu

Comment: put php in the [path](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) - bingo

Comment: And once php is in your PATH you will be pleasently surprosed to find you no longer need to type php.  app/console will work by itself thanks to the first line in the console file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php related error in linux terminal while setting up symfony framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117665/php-related-error-in-linux-terminal-while-setting-up-symfony-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put "/usr/local/php7/bin/" to $PATH or use shell alias command with writing following line to console:

```
alias php=/usr/local/php7/bin/php
```

after that you can use "php app/console"